# How do I move an already existing layout up in Android 2.3?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have an activity that displays an image with a mostly transparent grey box on the bottom. The grey box displays the name of the image, and the photographer. I have implemented code that will animate the new text as if it came in through the bottom of the screen. The grey box, however, is not animated. I'd like it to animate so it slides up with the new text, but I'm not sure how to do that in SDK version 9 (I've google this extensively). I've tried a `LayoutTransition` but my min SDK version is 9, and it has to at least be 11 to use that class. Due to legal considerations, I cannot use any non-google libraries. Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your grey box is a view or layout of some sort, just apply the same animation that you apply to your TextView.

If possible, you could also set the grey as the background of the TextView, so that you only have to animate one view.